# How to display a list in the body of an expansion panel?

Tags: flutter

I'm building a mat expansion panel list :

```
Widget _buildAccordion() {
    return ExpansionPanelList(
      expansionCallback: (int index, bool isExpanded) {
        setState(() {
          panels[index].isExpanded = !isExpanded;
        });
      },
      children: panels.map<ExpansionPanel>((CalendarDayPanel panel) {
        return ExpansionPanel(
            canTapOnHeader: true,
            headerBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded) {
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(panel.calendarDay.dateString),
                subtitle: Text('${panel.calendarDay.appointmentsNumber} rdv.'),
              );
            },
            body: ListView(children: [
              ListTile(title: Text("1st tile")),
              ListTile(title: Text("2nd tile"))
            ]),
            isExpanded: panel.isExpanded);
      }).toList(),
    );
  }
```

I want the body of each ExpansionPanel to display a list of tiles. However I have render error when I try to expand the panel. If instead of ListView in the body, I use a simple Text widget it works fine.

What should I do to display a list in the body of my expansion panel ?

Full error message logged is :

> RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#e926c
> relayoutBoundary=up24 NEEDS-PAINT

**Update**

Changed body to :

```
body: ListView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          children: [
            ListTile(title: Text("1st tile")),
            ListTile(title: Text("2nd tile"))
          ],
      ),
```

Still trying to grasp the underlying logic here.

Comment: see here https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollView/shrinkWrap.html

 If the scroll view has unbounded constraints in the scrollDirection, then shrinkWrap must be true.

Answer (score 0):

```
Widget _buildAccordion() {
  return ExpansionPanelList(
    expansionCallback: (int index, bool isExpanded) {
      setState(() {
        panels[index].isExpanded = !isExpanded;
      });
    },
    children: panels.map<ExpansionPanel>((CalendarDayPanel panel) {
      return ExpansionPanel(
          canTapOnHeader: true,
          headerBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(panel.calendarDay.dateString),
              subtitle: Text('${panel.calendarDay.appointmentsNumber} rdv.'),
            );
          },
          body: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: ListView(children: [
                  ListTile(title: Text("1st tile")),
                  ListTile(title: Text("2nd tile"))
                ]),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          isExpanded: panel.isExpanded);
    }).toList(),
  );
}
```

Change above.. Wrap ListView by Expanded and Expanded by Column.

Comment: tried this with no success. However, adding shrinkWrap to the list worked. Still does not grasp exactly why.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these to ListView.builder:
shrinkWrap: true,
physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),

See the updated code:

```
Widget _buildAccordion() {
    return ExpansionPanelList(
      expansionCallback: (int index, bool isExpanded) {
        setState(() {
          panels[index].isExpanded = !isExpanded;
        });
      },
      children: panels.map<ExpansionPanel>((CalendarDayPanel panel) {
        return ExpansionPanel(
            canTapOnHeader: true,
            headerBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded) {
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(panel.calendarDay.dateString),
                subtitle: Text('${panel.calendarDay.appointmentsNumber} rdv.'),
              );
            },
            body: ListView(
shrinkWrap: true,
physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
children: [
              ListTile(title: Text("1st tile")),
              ListTile(title: Text("2nd tile"))
            ]),
            isExpanded: panel.isExpanded);
      }).toList(),
    );
  }
```